# pulling out the result from MATLAB to Excel row by row

Tags: excel, matlab

I do calculations on 64 elements (`for p=1:64 function end`) and pull out the result values in an Excel file.

Is there any way to arrange the result values for each element row by row (the values of the first element should appear on the first row, the values of the second element should appear on the second row and so on)?
I used `P=reshape(A,[],16)` but Matlab pushes the values from right to the left mixing them.

For example, 
If I set the loop for the calculation `p=1:1` and use `P=reshape(A,[],16)` the result is:

```
                  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

- If I set `p=1:2` the result becomes:
  for element 1:        1 3 5 7  9 11 13 15 **17** 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 
  for element 2:        2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16  **18** 20 22 24 26 28 30 32

(the values of element 2 are: 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 ... 32)

- The result for `p=1:2` should be: 
  for element 1:         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
  for element 2:        **17** ***18*** 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 
  for element 3:         33 34 35 ,etc...

Comment: Posting an example would help clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
P=reshape(A,16,[])'
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But it works only for the first 8 elements. Then, Matlab starts pushing to the left again.

Comment: Is there any way to make Matlab work in this way for all 64 elements?

Comment: What do you mean by "starts pushing to the left again"? I've tested on a vector `A = 1:64`, it seems ok.

Comment: By 'pushing to the left' I mean the following result: for element 1:  the values 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 appear on the first row and the values 9 10 11 12 ...16 appear on the second row. Then, on the thirs row comes the second element with values from 17...24 and on the row four values from 25...32 and so on. And this happens when I set for p=1:64 (elements).